# Blender textures are rendered on each triangle individually

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

If I make a new texture, then it draws the same tiny texture on each triangle of whatever I'm drawing. If I modify the material on the cube on the starting scene, it works fine. But I can't figure out how to copy materials, so I can only have one material per scene.

My problem seems similar to the one [here][2], but when I tried their solution, it ended up projecting it onto the UV map. I'm making a procedural texture on a sphere. If I use the UV map, it gets really warped on the poles.

Here's a picture:

[image: Textured spheres]

The sphere on right is what I want. I made it by modifying the material on the starting cube. It is textured as if it was carved from a solid block of wood.

The sphere in the middle is what I get if I apply a new texture to a sphere. Each triangle is individually given a 2d texture.

The sphere on the left is what happens if I UV unwrap it. It mostly looks okay, but it's really warped at the poles and it has a seam. there are other ways to unwrap it, but there's no good way to put a 2d texture on a 3d object.

Comment: Can you add a picture to your question please? Showing the problem will give visual clues as to how help and what suggestions to make to guide you in the correct direction.

Comment: Still not too sure what your question is ... is it about having one material per scene? or is it about UVmap stretching ? Is it a procedural texture question where it does not involve a jpg image but a computer generated algorithm like noise or cloud? A sphere generally get stretched UV. It all depends on how you unwrap one.

Comment: The problem is that it's using UV when it should be using xyz. Procedural textures are built to work in three dimensions. They do work that way on the starting cube. But if I build my own, they only use UV coordinates, which necessarily get stretched on a sphere.

Comment: Alright I am starting to understand your question ... so you are saying that you have written your own procedural code and made a procedural texture but it's behaving like a texture map like a .jpg or .tga that only reference the UV, where it should have referenced UVW? If that is the case I may not have enough knowledge on the subject. Sharing some code from your procedure code may help others to understand your problems better.

Comment: I didn't write code. I just used the built-in wood texture.

Comment: @DanielLC, are you using UV or generated coordinates? If UV, I would try generated and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the mesh does not have an UV map, the polygons still have default UV coordinates. The default maps the whole 2D texture to the entire polygon. That's why every face separately repeats what you see in the texture preview.

[image: texture preview in the sidebar next to render of UV sphere with that texture]

But to actually get this, coordinate mapping has to be switched to UV.

[image: sidebar scrolled to texture mapping settings]

The procedural wood texture is a 3D texture. It can use 3D coordinates to calculate the color. But only if the coordinate mapping is of a 3D kind. UV is 2D mapping.

[image: the UV sphere now shows stripes instead of a strange triangular pattern]

The "Object" coordinate mapping is a 3D mapping. Normally it is based on the bounding box of the mesh, but it can be changed in the Texture Space settings for the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try unwrapping in a **sphere projection**:
[image]

Also, enable smooth shading:
[image]

Comment: I tried that. It draws the texture on the UV map, which means it ends up really warped at the poles.